# "I went back up the stairs to ..." or "I went up the stairs back to ..."

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about where you can put the word "back" in a certain sentence.

When you are working on the 4th floor, someone wants you to bring printer paper to the 2nd floor. So you go downstairs, deliver the printer paper, and then you go up the stairs to the 4th floor to return to work.

When you are talking about this event, which sentence can you say?

> After delivering the paper, I went **back** up the stairs to the fourth
> floor.
>
> After delivering the paper, I went up the stairs **back** to the fourth
> floor.

I don't know which is the normal way of saying this, "went back up the stairs to" or "went up the stairs back to."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical and idiomatic.

The first sentence suggests that you probably came down the stairs and you went back the same way.

The second sentence, where **up the stairs** is placed next to the verb, maybe suggests that you made a conscious choice to use the stairs (rather than, for example, the lift).

As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went%20back%20up%20the%20stairs%2C%20went%20up%20the%20stairs%20back&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20back%20up%20the%20stairs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20up%20the%20stairs%20back%3B%2Cc0) shows, the form used in the second sentence is extremely uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the phrases ***to go back** (up)* and ***to go up the stairs***. ***Up the stairs*** is not the place you wish to return to. So

> I went up the stairs ***back to the fourth floor***.

is more accurate, because ***the fourth floor*** is your departing point. And in your OP you clearly explain that you want your sentence to mean ***return to work***.